# Vertically centering a div in a 100% height div doesn't work on Mobile Safari

Tags: ios, css, mobile-safari, sass

I'm trying to put a div inside another div that stretches to the full height of the screen and center it vertically, like so:

[Preview http://f.cl.ly/items/1a3L46453f0D271V1O2w/Schermafbeelding%202013-04-02%20om%2021.37.25.png](http://f.cl.ly/items/1a3L46453f0D271V1O2w/Schermafbeelding%202013-04-02%20om%2021.37.25.png)

The large photo is the full screen div, the white band is the vertically centered div.
The solution below works gracefully on all possible computers and browsers that I tried... except for Mobile Safari.
For some reason, Mobile Safari (at least on iPad) decides to put the nested div 50% down the page instead of 50% down its parent div.

HTML:

```
<div class="band full">
    <div class="band">
        *content*
    </div>
</div>
```

SCSS (irrelevant tags removed):

```
div.band{ //General styling for div.band elements
    margin: 0px;
    padding: 80px 0px;
    width: 100%;

    &.full{ //Style the parent div
        height: 100%;
    }

    div.band{ //Style the nested div
        position: relative;
        top: 50%;
        margin-top: -200px;
        padding: 20px 0px;
        height: 400px;
    }
}
```

I've got a nagging feeling that this is a bug in Mobile Safari. I sure hope it isn't. Does anyone know how to fix this?

Comment: have you tried setting height and min height to 100% on the html tag? Also add height 100% on the body tag. You should probably remove that height 400px on div.band too. Try separating the height/width styles into a wrapping div, put the padding and stuff in a child div. if you put up a fiddle of all your code i can help you better

Comment: @MattLambert Fiddle. It's based on SCSS output, but I tried to clean it up a bit.
http://jsfiddle.net/gr5Cs/

Comment: @MattLambert Okay. The Fiddle doesn't display the issue on iPad. I'm trying to make a new one, just a moment.

Comment: @MattLambert Hahaha, I'm seriously stumped on this one. I'm inspecting the page on iPad through Safari on my Mac now, and every time I select the element, it gets pushed down another 100px or so.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I really did my best to solve this in a clean manner, but I ran some more tests and it's clearly a bug in Mobile Safari's rendering engine. I decided to solve it with an admittedly dirty jQuery hack, but at least it works now.

My page had one of these full screen photos with a band in the middle on the very top, and another one on the very bottom of the page. The top one was easy to solve: just use absolute positioning instead of relative (which was positioning relatively to the top of the page anyway). The "top" property of the bottom band, on the other hand, has to be recalculated based on the height of the page after setting its positioning to absolute. I solved this by setting the "top" property to this: vertical offset from the top of the page to the bottom band + (the height of the full screen band to center in / 2).

Or in code form:

```
$(window).load(function() { //Wait until the page is fully loaded
    if (navigator.userAgent.match(/(iPod|iPhone|iPad)/)) { //If the user is using an iDevice
        $('div.band#top div.band').css('position', 'absolute');
        $('div.band#bottom div.band').css('position', 'absolute');
        $('div.band#bottom div.band').css('top', $('div.band#bottom').offset().top + ($('div.band#bottom').height() / 2));
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

check this out. Not tested on mobile but should work

HTML

```
<div class="panel">
 <div class="panelInner">
  <div class="box">
   <div class="boxInner">hi there</div>
  </div>
 </div>
</div>
```

CSS

```
html {
min-height: 100%;
height: 100%;
}

body {
height: 100%;
margin: 0;
}

.panelInner {
padding: 40px;
text-align: center;
display: table-cell;
vertical-align: middle;
}

.box {
height: 200px;
background: #999;
display: table;
width: 100%;
}

.boxInner {
display: table-cell;
vertical-align: middle;
}
```

And here's a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/cardeo/XuHQH/1/)

Comment: Also not quite what I'm looking for, because I'm trying to center a block with a background color. Using a table cell for the inner panel would fill up the entire outer panel.